# splitting the source data to have the specific data oracle

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a source field from oracle db table data type VARCHAR2(512 CHAR) which is like this

```
%custId{str:hGl0EWJsRTwweerRkaaKsdKDsqKm0123}
%prod{str:BalanceAmount}%logistic{str:Logistic}%hiringdate{str:1999-02-28T11:10:11p}%custId{str:FpseikiD0Jt1L0Mskdww8oZBjU4La123}
```

but when i consider for my extract i must only consider only data with %cusId pull data and only this alphanumeric data has to be captured and populated for the extract , the problem is this is just one example from source there can be any number of combinations but i have to only consider %custId with 
%custId{str:**hGl0EWJsRTwweerRkaaKsdKDsqKm0123**}

i need to use which function substr,lpad ?

after using the below query

```
SELECT
    field,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(field, '%custId\{.*?\}') AS custId
FROM yourTable
where col_source='%prod{str:BalanceAmount}%logistic{str:Logistic}%hiringdate{str:1999-02-28T11:10:11p}%custId{str:FpseikiD0Jt1L0Mskdww8oZBjU4La123}'
```

**Result**

%custId{str:FpseikiD0Jt1L0Mskdww8oZBjU4La123}

but expected result

**FpseikiD0Jt1L0Mskdww8oZBjU4La123**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` here:

```
SELECT
    field,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(field, '%custId\{(.*?)\}', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS custId
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Hi Tim for example  %custId{str:FpseikiD0Jt1L0Mskdww8oZBjU4La123}    but i need the result as only this FpseikiD0Jt1L0Mskdww8oZBjU4La123